# Установка своей библиотеки в число стандарных Java

Tags: java

Всем добрый день, хочу сделать такую штуку. Я очень хочу сделать свою библиотеку, и хочу чтобы эта библиотека автоматически подгружалась в каждый проект, я так сказать хочу внедрить её в число стандартных пакетов java. Как мне такое сделать, чтобы заработало?

Comment: _Я очень хочу сделать свою библиотеку, и хочу чтобы эта библиотека 
автоматически подгружалась в каждый проект_
Ваш проект? или вообще любой проект любого разработчика? Если второй вариант, то см. ответ @ЮрийСПб. Если просто свою библиотеку в свои же проекты - то все проще...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. Можно лишь опубликовать её в публичном репозитории (`maven`, `jcenter` etc) и в каждом проекте вручную подключать. Если собирать через `gradle`, то подключать можно даже всего одной строкой. Выше этого не прыгнуть, если не рассматривать координацию с руководством разработки самого языка.

Как залить свою библиотеку в публичный репозиторий - смотрите тут (немного устарела статья, но с помощью бубна можно добиться результата): [How to distribute your own Android library through jCenter and Maven Central from Android Studio](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en)

Да, там про андроид, но и для просто Java всё тоже самое

Answer (score 1):

Для этого Вам надо скачать OpenJDK с репозитория, написать и внедрить свои классы и/или пакеты, написать и прогнать юнит-тесты (проверить, чтобы ничего не падало, особенно это касается Jigsaw). Потом собрать JDK, написать и прогнать тесты уже на собранной Java-машине.