# Как сделать созданные в Android Studio классы общедоступными для всех проектов?

Tags: android-studio, project

Я создал несколько классов, но пока они принадлежат одному проекту. Что можно сделать в качестве альтернативы копированию файлов *.java в другие проекты, чтобы эти классы можно было там использовать?

Comment: создать [библиотеку](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html)

Comment: а если создать библиотеку, то классы в ней можно будет при необходимости модифицировать?

Comment: Вы хотите модифицировать из любого проекта, использующего эти классы, и чтобы изменения отражались на всех таких проектах разом?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/720595/17609

Comment: ну не разом, а просто, чтоб эту библиотеку можно было править

Comment: [аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/483399/177345)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я решил эту проблему таким образом, что появилась возможность использовать библиотеку одновременно в двух проектах, и даже редактировать её, не выходя из проекта.

В settings.gradle необходимо прописать:

```
include ':app', ':имя_вашей_библиотеки'
project(':имя_вашей_библиотеки').projectDir = new File('путь_к_вашей_библиотеке')
```

Затем в build.gradle указать в dependencies:

```
implementation project(':имя_вашей_библиотеки')
```

Всё работает замечательно!